# JNDI "Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I'm using JBoss Server for EJB And I need JNDI in console app to get reference of session bean,
console app code looks like this

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;


public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Properties pr = new Properties();
        pr.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        pr.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(pr);

    }

}
```

when I run the application I get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Program.main(Program.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: I added and I adde also jboss-remote-namging. but now I'm getting error like this   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xnio/Options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following context to connect.
I have tried and tested to set up this.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;


public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
      Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
    jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,         
    "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpassword");
    jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
    Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
    }

}
```

Then i got this error

```
JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: 
Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed - Could 
not register a EJB receiver for connection to remote://localhost:4447  
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication 
failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed.
```

Then i added the user using add-user.sh.

[image]

**Successful Handshake** message came.

Comment: when i Instatiate InitialContext class and run it I get the error    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xnio/Options

Comment: there is no need to add any jar . just add jboss.client present in jboss. Try using this ----- Context initialContext;
        initialContext = new InitialContext(pr); in your code.

Comment: can you please show me thi link where can i download jboss.client jar file

Comment: At your local machine follow path ---jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\client

Comment: Look it is finding xnio at my side. Console.log
 Jan 19, 2014 12:27:24 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Jan 19, 2014 12:27:24 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Jan 19, 2014 12:27:24 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA

Comment: at last worked I was adding jboss-client (5.0 version) an there was not class InitialContextFactory I adde 7.0 version and worked thanks!

Comment: :( . have you got ssl exception on your side.

Comment: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [remote://localhost:4447] i am getting this error now when i try to lookup a Session bean

Comment: comment this line.jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
Check your standalone.xml for 4447 is entry present. Add this in standalone.xml
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.2">
                 <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>

Comment: Vinayak Pingale - might I suggest updating your answer to address the part of the question that deals with the class not found exception like @Jagdish-Chandra does.

Answer (score 12):

To overcome above error you need to pay attention to two points.
First , You need to have **jboss-client.jar** in **classpath**.
Second, according to Jboss version you are using you need to change your **provider url**.

For **JBossAS 5** you should set following properties in environment

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.NamingContextFactory");
env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099");
```

For **JBossAS 7** you should set following properties in environment

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447"));
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME));
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD));
```

Comment: After adding the jboss-client.jar its throwing a different error


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: When I added jboss-client.jara I got the mistake: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo

Answer (score 2):

you may need add jboss-client.jar and jboss-ejb3-common-client.jar into your library

Answer (score 0):

You need dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-remote-naming/

For WildFly you can use org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory form:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-naming-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-naming-client

You can use bom file for import:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-ejb-client-bom