# How do I look up my datasource in JBoss jndi

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, jndi

My JBoss console app says my datasource is "java:/mydb"

If I use

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) (new InitialContext()).lookup("java:/mydb");
```

I get a NoInitialContextException.
If I do a

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) (new InitialContext()).lookup("java:/mydb");
```

I get a IllegalArgumentException No Matching XNIO provider found. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What is context of your call, can you use annotations? `@Resource(mappedName="{jndi-name}")` annotation on a DataSource member of a @Stateless annotated bean is working for me.

Comment: We have several web applications that use this DataSource without a problem although they are on the same instance of JBoss. The program I'm writing right now is a batch program that will reside on a different server outside of JBoss.

Comment: What kind of application server is the batch program runing on, if it's outside of JBoss?

Comment: It isn't. It is running on a Linux distro.

Comment: Your question may be answered by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213922/5284850 it indicates that the XNIO problem could be due to missing jboss-client.jar, but you would also need to specify `InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL` and a couple of other parameters as described there.